# How to make Powerline fonts work with iTerm2

Tags: terminal, mojave, font, iterm

I have a problem with using [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) fonts in the iTerm2. I followed the tutorial for installation and I have chosen Hack font in the profile settings (Non-ASCII is set just to make sure). My `.zshrc` file is [here](https://pastebin.com/0Ng8Cex6) if it helps.

[image]

However, the prompt still looks like this

[image]

I am running Mojave with ZSH 5.7.1 (I am not sure if any ZSH configuration applies to this issue). Thanks a lot for help

Comment: [Nerd font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) might help. There's no harm in trying I guess.

Answer (score 23):

Go to iTerms2 Preferences (<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) then go to Profiles and check the box called "Use build-in Powerline glyphs"

[image]

Comment: wow! so beautiful

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the setup that you did. But the following process worked on my system:

*https://medium.com/@elviocavalcante/5-steps-to-improve-your-terminal-appearance-on-mac-osx-f58b20058c84*

I suggest you change the theme from default **ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"** to **ZSH_THEME="agnoster".**

The above guideline helped me to get the font in terminal and in iterm2 too

[image]

Comment: I am not using Oh My Zsh, I attached my `zshrc` if it helps. But yes, I followed the steps 4 and 5, otherwise I wouldn't be able to add the fonts into the iTerm.