# My PS1 Customized Terminal Prompt doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, iterm

I moved from Windows and my customized terminal prompt doesn't work anymore, I'm trying to figure out the reason for that. It's not working in iTerm2 or RoyalTSX or Terminal.

[image]

On windows:

[image]

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;34m\]\[\033[0;32m\] ~B \[\e[0;42m\]\[\e[42m\] \u \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[44m\] ~B \[\033[0;34m\]\[\033[44m\]\[\033[0;30m\]\[\033[44m\] \w \[\033[0m\]\[\033[0;34m\] ~B  \[\033[1;36m\]$ \[\033[0m\]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are complaining about 2 things.

1. The colours - that you alter in the Terminal preferences.
2. Not getting the arrow characters but a questionmark, The question mark in a box is placeholder for a symbol from a font set it doesn't recognize. You require a powerline font. For iTerm2 see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/413332/237)